# How to exclude file from PhpStorm global search (Ctrl+Shift+F)

Tags: php, search, phpstorm

I want to exclude a file from the PhpStorm global search (Ctrl+Shift+F) but not exclude the file from the project itself. A good use case would be to avoid searching inside files like jQuery.js, but in my particular case, I have a plugin that generates code and it clutters my search results.

Being specific, this is the example search result:
[image: search-results]

The first result is uselss and will always be for me. So I would like to exclude it from the results. However, if I exclude it from the project then it will not be included in the auto-complete features of PhpStorm, which is the sole purpose of that file in the first place.

Or are there any alternatives to this? I could select a folder and search only there, but it is not as convenient as just pressing Ctrl+Shift+F directly from the editor

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do that defining a [scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/scopes.html)

First of all you have to define a scope containing all the directories of your project that you want to be "searchable".

Go to `Appereance & Behaviour -> Scopes` and create the scope

Then, in the "Find in Path" window you can select the Custom scope you want to use for the search

Comment: Oh this is nice! at first I thought I had tried this solution before, but I followed it step by step and it is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you :--)

Answer (score 17):

Right-click on the folder > Mark directory as > Excluded

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the file is inside root folder of my project so I would have to exclude the whole project for this :p

Comment: Works for directories but not files. Files can be excluded from code completion by marking them as plain text but they are still included in global search.

Answer (score 3):

When You press Ctrl+Shift+F there is an option for scope where you can specify the files you want to search.

[image: PhpStorm]

Comment: non of the predefined options in the "custom:" select box helped me, it seems the file I want to exclude is part of the project and I cannot exclude it. Maybe if the VCS filters in that box included the option to search inside all version controlled files (and not just the changed ones) I could .gitignore the unwanted file and that would be enough. But no option exists.

Comment: I am also trying the "file masks" box but I have not found how to negate a mask. This way I could put the mask "oxid.meta.php" and search in files not matching the mask, but no luck yet.

Comment: You can negate masks with a preceding `!` exclamation mark. I.e. `!*.min.css,!*.min.js`

Answer (score 2):

You can go to settings/preferences -> Editor -> File Types and then add a rule to the Ignored Files and Folders.

[PhpStorm File Types settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEbHw.png)