# WebStorm/PhpStorm exclude file from search everywhere

Tags: php, filter, phpstorm, webstorm, directory-structure

When I search everywhere I would like to exclude JS and js.map files from the search results. ( I am using TypeScript ). My expected behaviour is to have these files omitted from Search Everywhere.

Yes, I can mark the files as plain text, but that's cumbersome on a per file basis.

I have used scopes:
[image]

I have researched these links:

- [PHPStorm exclude files by mask from indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168293/phpstorm-exclude-files-by-mask-from-indexing)
- [How to exclude file from PhpStorm global search (Ctrl+Shift+F)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772265/how-to-exclude-file-from-phpstorm-global-search-ctrlshiftf)

What am I missing? Can this be done?

Answer (score 5):

You can exclude particular directory from your project. Go:

```
Settings > Directories
```

after that select desired directory and press "Excluded" button.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but that excludes *everything*. The typescript and map files are in the same directory as the js and html files

Comment: Ah... I decided that all you js and js.map files nested in separated directory...

Comment: This does not exclude just from the search. For example, Local history is not working, too.